# VS2015 support for ssh protocol in git client

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-2015

VS2013 had no support for ssh protocol on remote Git repositories. I have read a few articles where the underlying C lib that the git client relied on has now had ssh support added and thus VS2015 hopefully now supports it too.

Does anybody know if SSH is supported and if so, what is the format for the URL for the remote repository since attempting with `ssh://` does not work?

Unfortunately we have to use ssh protocol for connection to this private git repository.

Comment: Don't see why it now gets marked as a duplicate nearly 2 years later since I asked the question in June 2015 and the duplicate it has been marked as was a month later in July 2015.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Git support for Visual Studio - Git, TFS, and VS put into Context](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GitSupportForVisualStudioGitTFSAndVSPutIntoContext.aspx)", Visual Studio uses **[libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/)** for Git support.

And libgit2 only got ssh support in May 2013 ([PR 1558](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1558), [libgit2 v0.19.0+](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/releases/tag/v0.19.0)), a bit late for VS 2013.

VS2015 should include a more recent version of libgit2, but ssh support wasn't yet planned.
See "[Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 and Team Foundation Server 2015 CTP Released](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/02/23/10593169.aspx)".

> Saeed Noursalehi [MSFT] 4 Mar 2015 4:45 PM #
>
> We have no immediate plans to support SSH

There is [an issue pending](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1109818).

> This discussion has been gaining more steam internally.
> I don't have a date yet, but it's something we'll take a hard look at in our next round of planning.

Comment: SSH support and multiple project wise repo support in a single VS solution is two key features required for the success of VS 2015 Git support.

Comment: ... for the sucess of VS2015.

Comment: Any update on this? i get "Unsupported URL protocol" error message

Comment: @YvonHuynh no update on my side. What version are you using?

Comment: I use VS2015,installed git version 2.10.0.windows.1, on Windows 10