# In what scenarios libgit2 is faster than git?

Tags: c, git, performance, libgit2

I can write a `Zsh` module with some subset of `git`-command features. The motivation is to accelerate prompts. Example prompt that I use does:

```
    changed_files=()
    git diff --quiet 2> /dev/null || changed_files=(${(f)"$( git diff --name-only 2>/dev/null )"})
```

This is not very fast when entering e.g. linux-kernel repo. I wonder if libgit2 could give more control over some typical tasks, and be faster this or other way.

I guess chances are low, because `Git` repository has simple structure, so `git` code is 1-to-1 reflection of it. But who knows? Any distinct `libgit2` performance trait is in my interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical scenario is when you have multiple chained git calls, each one having to open a shell/process.

But in 2017, most of the tools using libgit2 are starting to go back to a wrapping approach (wrapping git calls instead of relying on libgit2): Example [Visual Studio 15](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40059664/6309).

Git itself continues to evolve regularly and fixes bugs or introduces new features, and they are not always present in libgit2 (as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30842631/6309)).

In your case, for basic chained git functions, a C program calling libgit2 *might* be faster, but you need to measure it.